How do I deal with varying Visual Studio C++ Platform Toolsets when working on different systems?
What is the recommended way for dealing with the "Platform Toolset" setting in the Visual Studio C++ Configuration Properties when I'm using different systems with different versions of VS (and therefore different toolsets), when sharing the code via source control, e.g., Git?
For a long time now I have always manually changed the setting, then taken care to not submit the changed file, but this is always a tedious hazzle, especially when I did make changes on the project file, but I don't want the Toolset setting to be overwritten.
It is quite cumbersome to do this manually every time, there has to be a better way. I guess what I want is a "use the VS default" or "use the latest version available", which is however not available an option.
How do other people handle this in practice?

Why do you need to change the toolset version locally? Doesn't newer Visual Studio support the committed older toolset version?

Not if it's not additionally installed. E.g., VS 2017 (v15) comes with v141, VS 2019 (v16) with v142, VS 2022 (v17) with v143.
